# Change value of flip toggle dynamically with jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile

I'm working with jQuery Mobile, and I save some settings in a cookie. When the settings page is reloaded, I read the cookie to set all the values. I'm having trouble setting the [flip toggle switch](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a2/#docs/forms/forms-switch.html). Most elements just have to trigger the `keyup` or `changed` events, but I'm not sure how the flip toggles gets its value from the select box. Any ideas?

Answer (score 24):

After you change the value of the switch you have to refresh it for the animation to toggle:

```
$('#Switch2').val('on').slider("refresh");
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like it's broken.

Go to the page: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a2/#docs/forms/forms-switch.html  and use firebug console to run the following:

```
$('#slider2').val('on').trigger('keyup');
```

it changes the width of "on" part of the switch, but doesn't move the slider.

So the answer is: wait for the release of JQM :)

Bug issued here: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/issue/676

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to achieve this is to set the value, trigger the create and refresh.
Afterwards you need to trigger the slidestop event to perform any action you bound to the slider. eg:

```
$('#mySlider').val('on').trigger('create').slider("refresh");
$('#mySlider').trigger('slidestop');
```

I've tested this on jQuery mobile ver. 1.3.0

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just set the value in select like normal HTML and flip toggle switch will pick up automatically. i.e.

```
<select name="slider" id="slider" data-role="slider">
  <option value="off">Off</option>
  <option value="on" selected="selected">On</option>
</select>
```

Comment: But he uses cookies, so it's happening on a loaded page, with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Using `$('#slider2').val('on')` will change the value, as it is supposed to. However, it does not add the CSS classes such as `ui-btn-active` to the `option`, nor does it remove that class from the the `option`. If you want to dynamically change the `option`, then you will have to take care of those parts manually (not jQuery Mobile).

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
 if (someCondition) {
         $('#slider').val('off');
     }
     else {
         $('#slider').val('on');
     }
     try {
         $('#slider').slider("refresh");
     }
     catch (err) {
         console.log ("Error occurred refreshing slider (probabily first time!)");
     }
```