# How to change the jquery mobile flip switch state from code

Tags: javascript, jquery, android, jquery-mobile

I have some jQuery Mobile flip toggle switches on my Android/iPad application, and I need to
change their states (on/off) dynamically, using JavaScript.
I was looking for a solution here, ([Change value of flip toggle dynamically with jQuery Mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4263858/change-value-of-flip-toggle-dynamically-with-jquery-mobile)) and I tried several ways (`.val('on')`, `.slider('enable')`...) but it seems the control is not working at all.

Is there a solution for this issue? How can I do to change the flip switch state from code?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I've examined the page you posted and I confirmed that the solution:

```
$('selector').val('value').slider('refresh');
```

does indeed work. Make sure that 'selector' is referencing your select element, and that 'value' is a value you defined on the option element you wish to enable.

I confirmed this by visiting http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/forms/switch/index.html, then with firebug's console entering the line:

```
$("#flip-b").val('no').slider('refresh');
```

It switched the second slider displayed on the page from yes to no.

Answer (score 8):

There are *two* types of **flipswitch**, *select* based and *checkbox* based.
To set a *select* based widget, use the `.val()` construct

```
$("#myFlip").val("on").flipswitch( "refresh" ) ;
```

where "on" is one of the option values in the select element.

To set a *checkbox* based widget, use the `.prop()` construct:

```
$("#myFlip").prop( "checked", true ).flipswitch( "refresh" ) ;
```

where `true` is either `true` or `false`. (Thanks to Jeremy Hill for the hint).

BTW I tried the `.flipswitch( "option", "checked", true )` construct with no luck.

Note there is also a **slider** switch similar to the select based **flipswitch**.

Comment: I had to use `attr` as for some reason the flipswitch went into an infinite loop! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17027566/how-to-check-checkbox-dynamically-jquery-mobile/67749920#67749920

Answer (score 6):

For JQuery 1.4 or later, if you want to toggle a flip switch dynamically

```
$("#flip").val('on').flipswitch('refresh');
```

Make sure that your **data-role** is **flip-switch** to make this work.

Good Luck !

Comment: data-role="flipswitch" (no hyphen)

Answer (score 3):

Does this work:

- http://jsfiddle.net/AYLpe/

JS

```
var fts = $('#flipMe');
fts.val('on');
fts.slider('refresh');
```

HTML

```
<label for="flip-a">Select slider:</label>
<select name="slider" id="flipMe" data-role="slider">
    <option value="off">Off</option>
    <option value="on">On</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Pizano's answer above worked for me.

I, too, was having this problem.  In my case, I was missing the all-important ".slider('refresh')"

Cheers,
Steve

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the 'flipswitch' part to work, so treating it like a normal checkbox might work for you (this is for jQuery Mobile 1.4.3):

```
$('input[name="my-flipswitch-name"]').prop('checked', true).trigger('click').trigger('change');
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to make flipswitches (checkbox-based and select-based), but you can can only dynamically change the state with the select-based method.

**Jquery to change state:**

```
$("#mySwitch").val('no').flipswitch('refresh');
```

**Select-based method:**

```
<select name="mySwitch" id="mySwitch" data-role="flipswitch" >
   <option value="no">No</option>
   <option value="yes">Yes</option>
</select>
```

**Checkbox-based: (can't change state dynamically)**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="mySwitch" data-role="flipswitch">
```

Answer (score -1):

`$("#mySwitch").val('no').flipswitch().flipswitch('refresh');`
seems to work, too.