# JQuery Mobile refreshing checkbox works only once - .checkboxradio('refresh') issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, checkbox, refresh

I ran into a strange problem. I've got a table with a checkbox column. I'm using JQuery Mobile checkboxes. I want a click on a row to be associated with click on the checkbox in this row.

**JS:**

```
$(document).on('pagecreate', function (event) {
    bindRowClick();
});

function bindRowClick() {
    $('.productTable').find('tr').click(function () {
        var chck = $(this).find('td.hyperLink').find('input[type=checkbox]:first');
        var chckStatus = chck.is(':checked');
        alert("chckStatus 1: " + chckStatus);
        alert("!chckStatus: " + !chckStatus);
        chck.attr('checked', !chckStatus).checkboxradio().checkboxradio('refresh');
        alert("chckStatus 2: " + chck.is(':checked'));
    });
}
```

**HTML:** this is inside `<td class="hyperlink">`

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" id="divCheckbox">
     <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="checkboxSelect" CssClass="custom chckSelect" 
          meta:resourcekey="checkboxSelectResource1" />
     <asp:Label ID="lblForChck" CssClass="lblForChck" AssociatedControlID="checkboxSelect" runat="server" 
          meta:resourcekey="lblForChckResource1" />
</fieldset>
```

**What's happening with when I click on row 1 time** (checkbox was not selected until now):

```
first alert returns: "chckStatus 1: false"
second alert returns: "!chckStatus: true"
third alert returns: "chckStatus 2: true"
```

**What's happening with when I click on the *SAME* row 2 time (checkbox was selected previously):**

```
first alert returns: "chckStatus 1: true"
second alert returns: "!chckStatus: false"
third alert returns: "chckStatus 2: false"
```

**And now the strange part**

When I click again on the same row - instead of selecting the checkbox (like the first time) I've got the following result:

```
first alert returns: "chckStatus 1: true"
second alert returns: "!chckStatus: false"
third alert returns: "chckStatus 2: false"
```

What I found that might be connected to this issue:
[Previously working ".checkboxradio('refresh')" now broken in a3](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/previously-working-checkboxradio-refresh-now-broken-in-a3)

Comment: Why are you binding `bindRowClick();` to `pagecreate`? plus, to refresh checkbox, you need only `.checkboxradio('refresh')` **not** `.checkbox().checkboxradio('refresh')`.

Comment: Both `pageinit` and pagecreate` yield the same result. About using `.checkboxradio().checkboxradio('refresh');` instead of `.checkboxradio('refresh');` the reason is that if you use only `.checkboxradio('refresh');` there is an error "Uncaught cannot call methods on checkboxradio prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'"

Comment: To over come this problem, check this answer, it's a timing problem http://stackoverflow.com/a/17009087/1771795 Another issue, you better use `.prop('checked', true)` instead of `.attr('checked', true)`

Comment: Wow ... with .prop is working. Thank you very much!! Can you please add your comment as an answer. :)

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you :)

Comment: I've also binding the function to `pageinit` now.

Comment: Yea, it's better, good luck :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Instead of using `.attr()` use `.prop()` and then `.checkboxradio('refresh')`.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/Pauph/)**

Comment: $('.selector').checkboxradio().trigger('create') was exactly what I needed. Thanks