# State of Checkbox remains same

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

```
$('#SaveCheckbox').attr('checked') != true
```

Intending to check the value of CheckBox by the above means , as found the solution , but its giving false always , either i check the checkbox or uncheck it.
Kindly help.
I am using **jquery-1.10.2.min.js** and **jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js** libraries.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery Mobile refreshing checkbox works only once - .checkboxradio('refresh') issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17612806/jquery-mobile-refreshing-checkbox-works-only-once-checkboxradiorefresh-is)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `prop()` instead of `attr()`

```
$('#SaveCheckbox').prop ('checked') != true
```

> As of jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method returns undefined for attributes
>   that have not been set. To retrieve and change DOM properties such as
>   the checked, selected, or disabled state of form elements, use the
>   .prop() method, [jQuery Docs](https://api.jquery.com/attr/)

You can also use `:checked`

```
if($('#SaveCheckbox').is(":checked"))
```

*OR*

```
if($('#SaveCheckbox:checked').length)
```